# Should I validate user right on server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation, server-side

This might look like a simple question but I was not able to find out an answer.

In an ASP.NET application I have a user interface with a listbox containing choices populated depending on the connected user. Let's say user A can choose between C1, C2 and C3 and user B can only choose between C1 and C2. During population of the listboxes, I verify the connected user rights and populate the listbox with values according to the user.

Now, when form is submitted, do I need to check at the server side that user B is not trying to send C3 as listbox choice (by forging the submitted form) or this is not possible ?

Comment: You should never trust data submitted from a client. Always validate. Especially on a public website. If you've got an internal hosted site on a secure network you can probably be a little more trusting. But that's a very specific scenario, and most of the time you should be validating.

Comment: Client side validation is usually done with Javascript/jQuery. But that can easily be disabled in the browser by it's user to bypass validation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's always safe to assume that you should be checking on both sides (i.e. the client-side values that were shown to the user and the server-side ones that were posted the server).

It should be a relatively simple check to ensure the values are valid prior to updating your database, and even if you had to hit the server to validate those values, it's likely better than risking bad data or permissions being set.

It'll vary depending on your scenario - but err on the side of caution and if you aren't sure, validate anyways.